# Javascript setInterval not detecting global variable change (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, scope, closures

I'm developing a React Native app for communication with BLE devices. To keep track of whether the connection is still established or not I use a state in my component.

```
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(props.route.params.isConnected || false);
```

In my `useEffect` hook I start an interval to repeatedly read status of my BLE device like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);
    updateStatusRepeatedly.current = setInterval(readStatus, 5000);
    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);
      clearInterval(updateStatusRepeatedly.current);
    };
  }, []);
```

The `readStatus` function is called every 5 seconds, which is working as intended. But the content of the should not be executed. So I wrapped it in a conditional statement based on the `isConnected` variable.

```
const readStatus = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    readAddedCharge();
    readPowerMeasurement();
  } 
};
```

The content gets executed every time. Even if the `isConnected` variable is set to false. I don't understand why, because other functions and components take `isConnected` into account properly.

Any idea why other functions and components would register the change of `isConnected`, but `readStatus` funcion called as a timer would not?

Comment: You might find [this article](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) useful by Dan Abramov, where he create a `useInterval()` hook

Comment: @amik provided me with the answer that solved my problem. But I'll definitiely take a look into this too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a React's function component. Let's do a minimum example:

```
function MyComp() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(foo); // this will always show 0
      setFoo(foo + 1);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
}
```

It is because in the scope of the function, `foo` is a `const` that is never changed. "Changing" foo means running the function again with a new value of `foo`, which you don't use anyhow because `useEffect(..., [])` is called only on first render.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Clear and re-create the interval on every component render
2. Store the value with `useRef` so that `readStatus` from first render always has a reference to up-to-date value

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with the useRef hook. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found a solution. We created a component that performs the interval, it calls an external function back on the react side of things. See code below for example.

```
   const intervalExample = () => {
     const [timeslots, setTimeslots] = useState([]);
     
     const loopingFunction = () => {
        if (timeslots.length > 0) {
            timeslots.map((val) => {
                if (val['purchasing'] == true) {                    
                    doStuff();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    const doStuff = () = >{
    }


     return <div><IntervalRunner onInterval={loopingFunction} milliseconds="5000" /></div>

}


const IntervalRunner = (props) => {
    const [increments, setIncrements] = useState(0);
    const intervalCall = () => {
        setIncrements(increments+1);
         
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
         props.onInterval();
         setTimeout(intervalCall, props.milliseconds)
    }
    , [increments])
     return '';
     
}
```

The bove component is fairly basic, it may need work. In the last few minutes, I realized we needed an on/off switch. Mods for that are below.

```
export const IntervalRunner = (props) => {
const [increments, setIncrements] = useState(0);
const intervalCall = () => {
    if(props.active){
        setIncrements(increments+1);
    }
     
}

useEffect(()=>{
     if(props.active){
        props.onInterval();
        setTimeout(intervalCall, props.milliseconds);
     }
}
, [increments, props.active])
 return '';
```

}

used with:

```
return <div><IntervalRunner onInterval={loopingFunction} milliseconds="5000" active={activeVar} /></div>
```